# WindowsCE merges partitions into single /YaffsPart1

Tags: embedded, windows-ce, platform-builder

I have created two yaffs partions like

a. /boot
b. /data

Generated "NK.bin" is copied to /boot partition and a text file "DATA.TXT" is copied to 
/data partition.

Within windows CE only /YaffsPart1 partition is shown which contains NK.bin and DATA.TXT both file.

Why the WindowsCE is not showing partitions named boot and data ?

Why it merges two partition into one /YaffsPart1 ?

I need a solution that Windows CE shows boot and data partition both

Regards,
Nahid

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you have to setup you partitions in the .reg file of your Yaffs driver for your BSP. There will be several registry keys for different partitions and their starting and ending address.

I assume you setup the partitions in the boot loader and after loading windows it shows as one partition? You have to setup the partition, but then also setup the same partitions in the Windows CE Image under the Yaffs driver registry keys. If you have that driver and its settings there will probably be a default one YaffsPart1 which uses the entire space

I did some searching on the CE documentation and did not see the settings, but here is what my driver settings look like (yours may differ)

```
; This is the way to add another partition
; Align to the block size.
;
;[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\StorageManager\Profiles\lpd_yaffsbd\YAFFS_PARTDRV\PART01]
; For NOR Flash Devices
;   "EndAddr"=dword:006C0000
;   "StartAddr"=dword:03C0000   
; For NAND Flash Devices
;   "StartBlock"=dword:00000FE0 ;B256 (make sure to change PART00 values to not over-run)
;   "EndBlock"=dword:  000001FF ;B511 (default size = 32MB or 128KB*256 Blocks)
; Common for NOR/NAND Flash 
;   "Name"="YaffsPart2"
;   "PartType"="0"
;   "ReadOnly"=dword:0
```

Comment: Thnaks for the answer, i also changed my driver .reg file and it works for me

Comment: @Md.NahidHasan upvote the answer if it helped ;-) oh and since you are the asker, mark as answer (green checkmark on the left)